# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:67001

Tags: shell, logging

I am facing the below error while running the script. The script is trying to invoke a webservice..and its succesfull in invoking the webservice. At the end.. its printing the sucessful msgs also, just its throwing some rrors with LOG UTILS in between. Please have a look and suggest..

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:67001
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at com . drivelogic.services.logging.LogConfig.isDevMode(LogConfig.java:89)
        at com.drivelogic.services.logging.DlLogger.isTraceLog(DlLogger.java:277)
        at com.drivelogic.services.logging.DlLogger.log(DlLogger.java:55)
        at com.drivelogic.common.util.LogUtils.log(LogUtils.java:114)
        at com.drivelogic.common.util.LogUtils.fine(LogUtils.java:252)
        at com.cccis.frm.reprocess.util.PublishUtil.invokeWebService(PublishUtil.java:304)
        at com.cccis.frm.reprocess.batch.SOABatchReprocessor.reprocess(SOABatchReprocessor.java:137)
        at com.cccis.frm.reprocess.batch.SOABatchReprocessor.main(SOABatchReprocessor.java:56)
```

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-2
        at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:83)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.newSocket(SocketMuxer.java:373)
        at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.newClientSocket(SocketMuxer.java:383)
        at weblogic.socket.ChannelSocketFactory.createSocket(ChannelSocketFactory.java:86)
        at weblogic.socket.BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.createSocket(BaseAbstractMuxableSocket.java:133)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.newSocketWithRetry(MuxableSocketT3.java:214)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.MuxableSocketT3.connect(MuxableSocketT3.java:383)
        at weblogic.rjvm.t3.ConnectionFactoryT3.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryT3.java:34)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.createConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1784)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.findOrCreateConnection(ConnectionManager.java:1424)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:443)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ConnectionManager.bootstrap(ConnectionManager.java:321)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreateRemoteInternal(RJVMManager.java:254)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMManager.findOrCreate(RJVMManager.java:197)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteServer(RJVMFinder.java:238)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateRemoteCluster(RJVMFinder.java:316)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreateInternal(RJVMFinder.java:205)
        at weblogic.rjvm.RJVMFinder.findOrCreate(RJVMFinder.java:170)
        at weblogic.rjvm.ServerURL.findOrCreateRJVM(ServerURL.java:153)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactoryDelegate.java:353)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:315)
        at weblogic.jndi.Environment.getContext(Environment.java:285)
        at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:667)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:223)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:197)
        at com.drivelogic.services.logging.QueueHandler.send(QueueHandler.java:60)
        at com.drivelogic.services.logging.DlLogger.log(DlLogger.java:66)
        at com.drivelogic.common.util.LogUtils.log(LogUtils.java:114)
        at com.drivelogic.common.util.LogUtils.fine(LogUtils.java:252)
        at com.cccis.frm.reprocess.util.PublishUtil.invokeWebService(PublishUtil.java:304)
        at com.cccis.frm.reprocess.batch.SOABatchReprocessor.reprocess(SOABatchReprocessor.java:137)
        at com.cccis.frm.reprocess.batch.SOABatchReprocessor.main(SOABatchReprocessor.java:56)
```

Answer (score 10):

the maximum port number is **65,535** and here is a [list of known service port](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xml) (The list is updated frequently). Try using a lower port number.

Comment: I am not sure where in the code the port is mentioned? any other way?

Comment: If you are unsure, I can never be sure too. Also, in your stacktrace, it mentions you use port number **-2** . Well, port number is from 1-65535