# IllegalArgumentException: port out of range (Wiremock + Docker)

Tags: java, docker, resttemplate, wiremock

I was trying to wiremock inside docker container but getting below error.
I tried to remove all docker containers and re ran it but still facing same issue. 
Please help me to fix it

Saw this post but it did not helped 
[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:67001](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657266/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-port-out-of-range67001)

**Docker entry point port number :**

```
--port 9000
```

**Stack trace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:90006

at java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:143)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:188)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
```

**docker ps**

```
5c335e25a982        test-wire-mock   "/bin/sh -c 'java -j…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp   test-wire-mock
```